# Central to their value proposition

Tags: meaning

I heard someone (whom I wasn't able to ask to explain the meaning) use the idiom "[blah blah blah] was `central to their value proposition`".  What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marketing term that means this is the value a company is trying to display to differentiate them from competition. A value proposition is the explanation of the potential value behind any decision.

An example: A pizza place may make good pizza but their fast delivery may be central to their value proposition.  So they would advertise how fast they get the pizzas to you vs. spend a lot of time on the quality of their pizza.